# Distributions Theory $ {u}\,{\sin((\pi)x)}=1.$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I am using Theory of distributions by Friedlander and Joshi. I want to find all $u$ in $D'(\mathbb R)$ such :

$$ {u}\cdot{\sin((\pi)x)}=1.$$

I see that any integer is a pole. Are there any simplifications?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f = pv(\frac{1}{\sin(\pi x)})$$ is a solution.

Then any solution is of the form $$u=f+w, \qquad w\sin(\pi x)=0$$ Given such a $w$, fix some $\psi \in C^\infty_c(-1,1)$, $\psi(0)=1$.

For all $\phi \in C^\infty_c(-1,1)$ we have
$$\langle w,\phi-\phi(0)\psi\rangle = \langle w\sin(\pi x),\frac{\phi-\phi(0)\psi}{\sin(\pi x)}\rangle=0$$
ie. $$\langle w,\phi\rangle= \langle C\delta,\phi\rangle,\qquad C = \langle w,\psi\rangle$$
Can you finish ?

Comment: Yes , thank you very much. Quite informative.