# Distribution Theory. How to solve $x^{m}{u}=\delta$?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I just got to study this topic and trying to get familiar with new sources.
I want to find all $u$ in $D'(\mathbb R)$ such :

$$ {x}^{m}{u}=\delta.$$
where $m$ is a positive integer.
My attempt was to try $u=\operatorname{p.v.} \frac{1}{x^m}$.

Any hint?

Comment: Consider $x\cdot \delta'=-\delta$...

Comment: $pv$ is for simple poles, for higher order poles you need the finite part stuffs. Then $x^m fp(1/x^m)=1$ not $\delta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul Garrett's comment gives a particular solution, then you'll need all the solutions to $x^m w=0$ that you'll find from the same method [as in your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3908791/distributions-theory-u-sin-pix-1/3908898#3908898) (take $\psi$ constant $=1$ on $[-1/2,1/2]$ to simplify the computation).

Comment: I really appreciate   your answers friends. I'm trying to  runderstand what's the finite parts integral definition. I read about the first and second order but find it difficult to deal in higher orders. Does it stem from Taylors theorem?